# Can I go to content files on root folder MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This happened on ASP MVC.
When i tried to get access files from "Views" it can't read it.
I tried to get it showing like **localhost:6036/Home(file content)** and not like **localhost:6036/Home/Home(file content)**

already tried to move Home.cstml to any folder but it didn't work at all. it still gets me a message **server error "/"**

and now this is what my href looks like on "_Layout.cstml"
**href="~/Views/Home">**

So is there any possible to get "localhost:6036/(this is a directory file which i can access)"
If yes, how to that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the link below, MVC denies direct access to your views (that ends either in aspx/ascx, either in cshtml/ vbhtml) :

https://forums.asp.net/t/1799101.aspx?How+deny+access+direct+URL+to+my+partial+views+

If you just want to share a file (like an image, or anything else) you should use the "Content" folder.

Hope it helps !